# Can't update a spesific document on Firestore using React Native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to develop a mobile app with React Native using Firestore as a database. I'm trying to update a specific document when the "handleLike" function is called. I've passed the id of the posts through handleLike function. I'm trying to update the "comment" field for the sake of the trial. The problem is it updates all of the documents in the database. Also handleLike function is called without me pressing the like button whenever I refresh the page. I get that it is in a loop but I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I would very much appreciate your help. I have added screenshots of the database and the console.

```js
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import { Ionicons, MaterialIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";
import { auth, storage, firestore,firebase } from "../firebase";
import { preventAutoHideAsync } from "expo-splash-screen";

import moment from 'moment';

function Feed() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  //const [deleted, setDeleted] = useState(false);

  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    try {
      const list = [];

      const profileRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(auth.currentUser.uid);
        const doc = await profileRef.get();

      await firestore
        .collection("posts")
        .orderBy('postTime', 'desc')
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          console.log("Total Posts: ", querySnapshot.size);

          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const pId = doc.id
            const { 
              userId,
              userName,
              userSurname,
              post,
              postImg,
              postTime,
              userImg,
              likes,
              comments,
              likeByUsers } = doc.data();
            list.push({
              id: pId,
              userId,
              userName,
              userSurname,
              userImg:userImg,
              post,
              postImg,
              postTime: postTime,
              liked: false,
              likes,
              comments,
              likeByUsers,
            });
          });
        });
      
      setPosts(list);

      if (loading) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
      console.log("Posts: ", posts);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  const renderPost = (posts) => { 
    const handleLike = (id) => {
    console.log(id)
    firestore.collection('posts')
    .doc(id)
    .update({
      comment: "tryout 2"
    })
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.feedItem}>
        <Image source={{uri: posts.userImg}} style={styles.avatar} />
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "space-between",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.name}>{posts.userName} {posts.userSurname}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.timestamp}>{moment(posts.postTime.toDate()).fromNow()}</Text>
            </View>

            <MaterialIcons name="expand-more" size={24} color="#73788B" />
          </View>
          <Text style={styles.post}>{posts.id}</Text>
          <Image
            source={{uri: posts.postImg}}
            style={styles.postImage}
            resizeMode="cover"
          />
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLike(posts.id)}>
            <Ionicons
              name="heart-outline"
              size={24}
              color="#73788B"
              style={{ marginRight: 16 }}
            />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Ionicons name="chatbox-outline" size={24} color="#73788B" />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headerTitle}>Feed</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addButton}>
          <Ionicons name="add-circle" size={32} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <FlatList
        style={styles.feed}
        data={posts}
        renderItem={({ item }) => renderPost(item)}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      ></FlatList>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  addButton: {
    position: "absolute",
    right: 30,
    top: 60,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#EBECF4",
  },
  header: {
    paddingTop: 64,
    paddingBottom: 16,
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: "#EBECF4",
    shadowColor: "#454D65",
    shadowOffset: { height: 5 },
    shadowRadius: 15,
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    zIndex: 10,
  },
  headerTitle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "500",
  },
  feed: {
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  feedItem: {
    backgroundColor: "#FFF",
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 8,
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginVertical: 8,
  },
  avatar: {
    width: 36,
    height: 36,
    borderRadius: 18,
    marginRight: 16,
  },
  name: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "500",
    color: "#454D65",
  },
  surname: {
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "500",
    color: "#454D65",
  },
  timestamp: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#808588",
    marginTop: 4,
  },
  post: {
    marginTop: 16,
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#838899",
  },
  postImage: {
    width: 267,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginVertical: 16,
  },
});
export default Feed;
```

Console Screenshot:

[image: Console Screenshot]

Firestore Database Screenshot:

[image: Firestore Database Screenshot]

Comment: `update()` returns a promise. Have you tried `await`ing it? Try an async function`const handleLike = async (id) => {` and `await ....update()`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. After trying what you suggested I got this error "TypeError: onPress is not a function. (In 'onPress(event)', 'onPress' is an instance of Promise)".

Comment: Can you try  `...update(...).then(() => console.log("Doc updated")).catch(e => console.log(e))` then without async function?

Comment: This time I get "Doc updated" 7 times on the console. It updates all of the documents again. The weird part is it does not update them when I click the like button but it happens when I refresh the page.